# Unexpected outcome when modifying an object in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a weird outcome when i modify an object within a function, the funny thing is that when i do the same thing in a browser console i get what i am expecting but in react it doesnt seem to be working
Here is the code

```
const makeChanges = i => {
  i.foo = "test";
  i["new"] = "i am new";

  return i;
};

function App() {
  var A = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
  };

  console.log(A);

  A = makeChanges(A);

  console.log(A);
  //the render code...
}
```

**Current outcome :**

```
Object {foo: "test", bar: "bar", new: "i am new"}
Object {foo: "test", bar: "bar", new: "i am new"}
```

**Expected outcome:**

```
Object {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
Object {foo: "test", bar: "bar", new: "i am new"}
```

[Here is a working example, please look at the console to see the result:](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-elbakyan-dt1nb?fontsize=14)

Comment: Are you working in Chrome? The Chrome console has some asynchronous behaviors that cause weird results like that.

Comment: Try using `console.log(JSON.stringify(A));` and you will get the correct data. The problem is with the debug tools.

Comment: @Pointy I am, but first of all i don't think thats chrome console because i was using `CodeSandBox` and second of all even after copying the value in a two variable before and after making the change and printing the variables in the render function i still get the same result

Comment: copying a variable, if you mean `var B = A` makes not difference as `A` is an object and it is copied by reference,not value.

Comment: In Firefox when I open the link with (native) console open it shows the expected outcome. If I open the console later, I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You modified the `i` so the original will also be changed. You can "clone" `i` by `const makeChanges = ({ ...i }) => `. Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-wave-mhnpp

Comment: If you add an `if` statement to test whether `A` has a "new" property before the call to `makeChanges()` you'll see that the property is not present. It's just the console being frustratingly misleading.

Comment: If you clone property the object, you can see the real result: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-chatelet-ive1n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you modified the `i` which points to the original object `A`.
To solve it, just "clone" the `i`:

Example:

```js
const makeChanges = ({ ...i }) => {
  i.foo = "test";
  i["new"] = "i am new";

  return i;
};
```

Or

```js
const makeChanges = (i) => {
  const result = { ...i };
  // or
  // const result = Object.assign({}, i);
  result.foo = "test";
  result["new"] = "i am new";

  return result;
};
```

Or

```js
const makeChanges = (i) => {
  return { ...i, foo: "test", "new": "i am new" } ;
};
```

The working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-wave-mhnpp

See the `spread (...)` syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Does this mean i am better off in performance if i don't use function ?!, because if i do i have to do a copy of each object i am going to modify, this is specially the case when the object has children and needs to be deep cloned!

Comment: @AliAhmadi *shallow copy* should be fine. You should keep the rest and just modify the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think rendering the output is async. And console.log keep reference of the objects it has to print. 
we also know if we are passing object as function attribute then it will b pass by reference 
So 
In this code object A has some address(**say abc**) to which it refer. 
And value at **abc** is value of object A 

When u pass A in function **makeChanges** the value at address **abc** got changed 
and console has to print the value at **abc** that's why same values are logged as at address **abc** value is same

If u want to see difference then u can make deep copy of object by **Object.assign**

```
const makeChanges = i => {
  i.foo = "test";
  i["new"] = "i am new";

  return i;
};

function App() {
  var A = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
  };

  console.log(A);

  A = makeChanges(Object.assign({},A));

  console.log(A);
  //the render code...
}
```

output will b

```
Object {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
Object {foo: "test", bar: "bar", new: "i am new"}
```

By `Object.assign({},A)`
U are creating new object at different memory so change this will not affect the value at memory **abc** (**abc** example)