# Adding new property recursively to an object fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following [Unexpected outcome when modifying an object in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728903/unexpected-outcome-when-modifying-an-object-in-a-function)
I learned that i have to clone the `item passed to the function` before changing it and returning it, and it worked for the said example, but when i tried it in my code which was a recursive code, it didn't work, here is an example showing this:

As you can see i intend to update the property `B` if it exists and if it doesn't i want to create a property B and then give it last value, but for some reason this fails !, of course if i create the property B before hand (before calling it recursively), i can give the value to it, but i don't know why this is needed or why my current code doesn't work!

```
function addB(item) {
  let newItem = { ...item };

  if (newItem.B) {
    newItem.B.value = "I am B";
  } else {
    newItem.B = {
      value: "I am B"
    };
  }

  if (newItem.children) {
    newItem.children.forEach(child => {
      //if you uncomment the code below, the code works!
      //child.B = {};
      child = addB(child);
    });
  }

  return newItem;
}

function App() {
  let parent = {
    id: 0,
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        children: [
          {
            id: 3
          },
          {
            id: 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  };

  parent = addB(parent);

  console.log(parent);
}
```

**Current output:**
[image: Current output]

**Expected output:**
[image: Expected output]

**[You can see this example and its result in this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-glitter-4788v?fontsize=14)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do the following:

```
function addB(item) {
  const newItem = { ...item, B: { value: 'I am B' } };

  if (newItem.children) {
    newItem.children = newItem.children.map(addB);
  }
  return newItem;
}
```

If you want to copy the B property if it exist and only set B.value then you can do:

```
const newItem = { ...item, B: { ...item.B, value: 'I am B' } };
```

```js
function addB(item) {
  const newItem = { ...item, B: { ...item.B,value: 'I am B' } };

  if (newItem.children) {
    newItem.children = newItem.children.map(addB);
  }
  return newItem;
}

console.log(
  addB({
    children: [
      {},
      { children: [{}, { B: { other: 2 } }] },
      { B: { something: 1 } },
    ],
  })
);
```

Another way to write this is:

```
var addB = item => ({
  ...item,
  B: { ...item.B, value: 'I am B' },
  ...(item.children
    ? { children: item.children.map(addB) }
    : undefined),
});
```

Comment: Oh cool alternative, i hadn't thought of that, by the way why is it that my current code doesn't work ?, where is the wrong part? i come from other languages and it really doesn't make sense for me why the current code doesn't work, thank you.

Comment: @AliAhmadi You don't assign `newItem.children` to a new value, you mutate the item but only after you make a shallow copy so it doesn't affect the original item.

Comment: don't i do `child = addB(child);` ? shouldn't making a shallow copy and returning the child, update that child?, i expected the items in children meaning the `child items` get updated.

Comment: @AliAhmadi For each item in children you add B but add B does not add the B property to the passed in item but to a copy of that item (this is good for react state because you should not mutate). So if you want newItem.children to change you need to re assign newItem.children with a new value. You can do this by mapping the children array using the addB function.

Comment: I see, i got the first half of what you said until "So if you want newItem.children to change", please bear with me for one more question, I can do something like this: `array.forEach(item => item.gold + 1)` which means by changing the item in `forEach` i changed the `array`, so why doesn't `child = addB(child);` work?, even if i am creating a new object inside `addB`, i am returning it and assigning it to the `child`, isn't this the same as increasing `item.gold` by one ?

Comment: @AliAhmadi The typical use of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is for side effects so you should not use it to change state by generating a new state. In your example you mutate item by setting item.gold. The function addB does not mutate because before setting the values of the item passed to addB it will make a `shallow copy` and mutates that copy.